# Show all Rows of Group with Group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this table called users in mysql with the following fields:

id, name, email

I want to see names of users which are registered with the same email address.

When i run the following query, i only can one row per group:

```
select name,email from users group by email having count(email) > 1;
```

I want to see all of the records inside the group which are having count(email) > 1.

Can i achieve this without using a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a subquery for that:

```
select name,email from users 
where email in
(
    select email from users group by email having count(email) > 1;
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain as to why Hamlet's answer has been downvoted?